# Grails/Groovy 2.5.0: Add resource in BootStrap.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, init

Is it possible to add a resource in the BootStrap.groovy file (init closure)?

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->
   modules = {
   'test2' {
      resource url:[file: 'js/myapp/r2.js']
      }
   }
}

def destroy = {
    // nothing to do
   }
}
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is add resources for a module in a pre-existing groovy file. eg myresource.groovy looks like so:

```
modules = {
  'test1' {
    resource url:[file: 'js/myapp/rs1.js']
  }
  'test2' {
    resource url:[file: 'js/myapp/rs1.js']
    #add more resources here through code
  }

 }
```

Comment: Do you want to run some code at startup and end of your script?  So far this looks pretty much like from Grails?

Comment: Yes, this is grails, and yes the init runs at startup.  It doesn't seem like the resource DSL syntax though.  Just wondering if there is another way to load resources for a module.